# Difference between .record and .tfrecord

Tags: tensorflow, roboflow

I've downloaded a dataset from https://public.roboflow.com/ which contains test.tfrecord and train.tfrecord

Is it the same than test.record and train.record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the file extension doesn't matter, they're in the [`TFRecord` format](https://blog.roboflow.com/create-tfrecord/). You can think of it a bit like a `zip` file though in that its structure can be freeform.

These specific ones are for use with the Tensorflow Object Detection API which expects the data inside the [`tfrecord`](https://roboflow.com/formats/tensorflow-tfrecord) to be laid out in a specific structure and order like this:

```
tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
```

There's a full tutorial on [how to train with the Tensorflow 2.0 Object Detection API here](https://blog.roboflow.com/train-a-tensorflow2-object-detection-model/).